# Code Refactoring Trying to use Polymorphism and std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constructor, polymorphism

I have this class

```
struct B {
   B( int x=0 ) { }
   virtual void something() {
          std::cout << "B()";
   }
};

struct A { 
     B b;
     int a;
     A( int a, int b_ ) : a(a), b(b_) {a}
};
```

I have implemented another class C

```
 struct C : public B {
   C( int x ) : B(b) { }
   virtual void something() {
          std::cout << "C()";
   }
};
```

What is the best way to get A use C instead of B ?

I already tried this :

```
struct A { 
         B  & b;
         int a;
         A( int a, B &b_ ) : a(a), b(b_) {a}
    };
```

But then I have to use `std::map<int, A>`
which is giving compilation errors:

```
'A::A' : no appropriate default constructor available.
```

so i did this :

```
struct A { 
             B  & b;
             int a;
             A( int a=0, B &b_=B() ) : a(a), b(b_) {a}
        };
```

in my main

```
std::map<int,A> mmap;
for( int i=0;i<5;++i ) {
   auto & b = C();
   mmap.insert( std::make_pair(i,A(i,b) ) ) ;
}
```

but these C's object in mmap's A become B as soon as `auto & b` goes out of scope.

Its not working. How to fix it ?

Comment: You can't bind temporaries to non-const references.

Comment: @chris what should i do then in the constructor of A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the A constructor, you try to assign a temporary instance of B to reference to B, which is illegal.

What you have to do is to change this reference by a pointer to this class :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct B {

   B( int x=0 ) { }
   virtual void something()
   {
        std::cout << "B()";
   }
};

struct A { 
        shared_ptr<B> b;
        int a;
        A( int a = 0, shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>(new B()) ) : a(a), b(b) {}
};

struct C : public B {
    C( int x ) { }
    virtual void something()
    {
        std::cout << "C()";
    }
}; 

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<B> b = shared_ptr<B>( new C(0));
    // Polymorphic test
    b->something();

    A a (0, b);
    // map test
    map<int, A> my_map;
    my_map[0] = a;

    return 0;
};
```

If you can not use C++11, just change smart pointers by naked pointers and handle the dynamic memory properly as usual. Or even better : use the Boost library, as mentioned by chris.

Comment: `make_shared` is a much better option for initialization, and there's always `boost::shared_ptr` pre-C++11 :)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention the boost library sorry. But I didn't know for make_shared. Thank you for the tips. Usually I use the "reset" method of the smart pointer, because it's simpler and shorter. (and also "auto")

Comment: is it not possible with Reference ?

Comment: No, because you have to have a default constructor for A which means that you have to pass to the reference a "fake" value if there is no parameter, which is illegal. You can achieve this with naked pointers but it will be ugly compared to the solution with smart pointer.

If you can't use C++11, you must take a look at the boost library to avoid a lot of headache during debugging and memory leak tracking :)